# cannot display chinese characters in php

Tags: php, html, character-encoding

Hi guys I have an issue to display chinese character in simple php file, I cannot figure out how to get it solved

```
<!--
To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
 <?php
 define('MAGPIE_OUTPUT_ENCODING', 'UTF-8');
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" value="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>

电视机/電視機
    </body>
</html>
```

I am think this can be the issue of apache or php.ini configuration. Any idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `<meta charset="utf-8">` before `<title>`

Some old style browers checks http header first, so you may set

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

or change your web server config file

Example in Nginx:

add this lines after `server {`

```
charset utf-8;
charset_types
    text/css
    application/javascript
    application/x-javascript
    text/xml
    text/plain;
```

Example in Apache:

```
AddDefaultCharset Off
```

or

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

Comment: And additionallu my web server is live, so I don't have really access to it

Comment: You know I have created another test.php file inside the live server. it shows fine but only I run the system it is not working

Comment: If I add manually some chinese char inside the html form it is ok. But once I am trying to pull it from database it stop to work. That's why to make sure that string comming from database is correct, I echo the data and exit. it is also fine. So I cannot understand how it can be happended?

Comment: It's the mysql problem, not PHP/Apache. for example, send query "SET NAMES utf-8" before mysql connected

Comment: Yes it is, you know, I think I found and issue, the problem is php cannot read chinese char.

Comment: finallyyyyyyyyyyy, I got the problem. htmlentities this was cousing a problem

Answer (score 2):

Try using this:

```
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
```

You write *value* instead of *content*

Cheers!

Comment: This worked fine. But when I pulled data from database it does show those funny characters. I checked the value bu echo and exit; the data is fine.

Comment: That usually happens because:    1) you codification of the database is not UTF-8    2) you php connection is not retrieving the data using UTF-8, try this: when you create your connection $conn = mysql_connect(host, user, password); then provide the codification with: mysql_set_charset('utf8',$conn);    Try this and tell if it works for my (works for me at least)

Comment: If that doesn't work, add this line too: mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

Comment: I spent all the day and could not fix it

Comment: Sorry to hear that, I managed to show Chinese characters using all of the above, [here's](http://fondue.litmon.com/badges/view?b=07da2bb42804917e10a9991e3c67833b) an example

Comment: Check php.ini file, look for _default_charset_ variable. Is it commented? In my server it is.

Comment: Yes it is, you know, I think I found and issue, the problem is php cannot read chinese char.

Comment: finallyyyyyyyyyyy, I got the problem. htmlentities this was cousing a problem

Answer (score 2):

As you are using html5 you can use

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

and it will your fix issue.

If you are not using html5 then changing value to content will fix it

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Comment: Not working, funny thing is that if you view souce code of page it is ok, but display some funny charaters

Comment: @Akram then it must be something else because it displays okay for me, you can see it also here http://jsfiddle.net/armababy/rz2vN/

Comment: @Akram if it still doesn't show for you correctly, maybe it's your browser encoding settings? I have seen for some people encoding in browser are set manually to some charset rather than to auto-detect.

Comment: Actualy in my local machine everything is working fine. the same script

Comment: Well this then is most likely a apache/ngnix or whatever server you use or incorrect sql setup.

Comment: finallyyyyyyyyyyy, I got the problem. htmlentities this was cousing a problem

Answer (score 0):

sorry did not get the question, but for thos who are getting the data from db try adding

`mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");` in your db connection

Comment: this give me some gibberish instead of question marks. Do you know what else I can use?